# Emulator runs in Virtualbox, but not in genymotion. why?

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

When I run the emulator in Genymotion, it opens and quickly disappears. But that same emulator, when i open in virtualbox, it seems to work fine. What may cause this problem? I am using Google Nexus S-4.1.1-API 16-480X800

Comment: Do you have `Intel Virtualization` option enabled?

Comment: cpu does not support virtualization

Comment: If this is the case, Genymotion will not work with the system..you can use a real device with USB Debugging mode ON